Aggregate columns that fall within range
I have two dataframes called df and ranges:
data = {
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
    'start': [10, 20, 15, 30, 25],
    'end': [50, 40, 60, 70, 45],
    'val1': [5, 10, 11, 12, 6],
    'val2': [5, 2, 1, 1, 0],
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = {
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'start': [0, 5, 25],
    'end': [50, 7, 35],
}


ranges = pd.DataFrame(data)

My goal is to aggregate the rows in df together based on whether they fall within the same range defined in ranges. I would like to aggregate them together such that for each val1, val2 column I get the min, max, mean, sum of that column within the context of the aggregation group.
The catch here is that I need to do this for something like 5000 ranges in ranges and 500,000 rows in df. So I'd like a fast but memory efficient (relatively) solution. I'm open to solutions using similar frameworks such as vaex.
Expected output where range_id is just a way to identify groups assuming they're not unique:
  range_id val1              val2             
            min max mean sum  min max mean sum
0        0    5   5  5.0   5    5   5  5.0   5


What is the benefit of range_id over just using group column to identify the groups? Can the same group have multiple ranges?

Yes, that wasn't shown in my example.

By "yes", do you mean: "yes, the same group can have multiple ranges"? E.g., the input for ranges could also be data = {'group': ['A', 'A'],'start': [0, 5],'end': [50, 7]}? If so, you've accepted an answer that does not (in its current form, at least) accommodate that (@mozway's otherwise excellent map approach)... And in that case, please update your question with an example of ranges that includes this possibility, along with the desired output based on that adjusted input.

Sorry I should've been clearer, yes the same group can have multiple ranges. I adjusted the example to describe this.

@donkey I see, however your example is not really explicit. There is no A that would match the second A group from ranges. Since this question already got many nice answers for the original description of the problem, I would recommend to open a new question with a well crafted example.

@mozway: I second that suggestion. @donkey: please revert the question to the previous version without duplicates in ranges. Then, create a new post for the variant with duplicates, linking back to this post for reference. In the new post, clearly show how the presence of duplicates changes the desired output, and include that output in the post. The recent update here invalidates all existing answers and negates the considerable efforts of multiple contributors, which is not how SO is supposed to work.

IIUC, I would pre-filter the dataframe with map and boolean indexing, then perform a classical groupby.agg. This should keep the masks and intermediate (filtered) DataFrame minimal for memory efficiency, and minimize the size of the input for groupby.
# columns to aggregate
cols = ['val1', 'val2']

# ensure data is numeric
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)

# optional, just to avoid having to `set_index` twice
tmp = ranges.set_index('group')

# pre-filter the rows for memory efficiency
# then perform a groupby.agg
out = (df[( df['start'].ge(df['group'].map(tmp['start']))
           &df['end'].le(df['group'].map(tmp['end'])))]
       .groupby('group', as_index=False)[cols].agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'sum'])
      )

Output:
  group val1              val2             
         min max mean sum  min max mean sum
0     A    5   5  5.0   5    5   5  5.0   5

Intermediate before the groupby:
  group  start  end  val1  val2
0     A     10   50     5     5

variant
@sammywemmy proposed an variation of my solution. Instead of computing all aggregations simultaneously in groupby.agg, you could compute them individually and combine them with concat. This is faster and potentially a bit more efficient memory-wise.
from itertools import product

cols = ['val1', 'val2']
tmp = ranges.set_index('group')

grouped = (df[( df['start'].ge(df['group'].map(tmp['start']))
               &df['end'].le(df['group'].map(tmp['end'])))]
          ).groupby('group')

aggs = ['min','mean','max','sum']

bunch = product(cols, aggs)
contents = []
for col, _agg in bunch:
    outcome = grouped[col].agg(_agg)
    outcome.name = (col,_agg)
    contents.append(outcome)

out = pd.concat(contents,axis=1)

timings

example generating function
def init(N):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'group': np.random.randint(0, 20, N),
                       'start': np.random.randint(0, 100, N),
                       'end': np.random.randint(0, 100, N),
                       'val1': np.random.randint(0, 100, N),
                       'val2': np.random.randint(0, 100, N),
                      })
    
    # ensure start <= end
    df[['start', 'end']] = np.sort(df[['start', 'end']], axis=1)

    group = df['group'].unique()
    ranges = pd.DataFrame({'group': group,
                           'start': np.random.randint(0, 110, len(group)),
                           'end': np.random.randint(0, 110, len(group)),
                          })
    ranges[['start', 'end']] = np.sort(ranges[['start', 'end']], axis=1)
    
    return df, ranges

memory_usage
on 10M rows
# mozway_pre_filter
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    49    711.2 MiB    711.2 MiB           1   def mozway_pre_filter(df, ranges):
    50                                             # columns to aggregate
    51    711.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       cols = ['val1', 'val2']
    52                                             
    53                                             # ensure data is numeric
    54    863.9 MiB    152.6 MiB           1       df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)
    55                                             
    56                                             # optional, just to avoid having to `set_index` twice
    57    863.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       tmp = ranges.set_index('group')
    58                                             
    59                                             # pre-filter the rows for memory efficiency
    60                                             # then perform a groupby.agg
    61    950.9 MiB     11.2 MiB           4       return (df[( df['start'].ge(df['group'].map(tmp['start']))
    62    881.6 MiB      9.5 MiB           1                  &df['end'].le(df['group'].map(tmp['end'])))]
    63    950.7 MiB    -66.6 MiB           2              .groupby('group', as_index=False)[cols].agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'sum'])


# donkey_merge
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    66    884.4 MiB    884.4 MiB           1   def donkey_merge(df, ranges):
    67    884.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       ranges = ranges.assign(range_id=ranges.index)
    68   1484.4 MiB    600.1 MiB           1       df_merged = pd.merge(df, ranges, on='group')
    69   1602.8 MiB    109.0 MiB           2       df_filtered = df_merged[(df_merged['start_x'] >= df_merged['start_y'])
    70   1494.0 MiB      9.4 MiB           1                               & (df_merged['end_x'] <= df_merged['end_y'])]
    71   1602.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       aggregation_dict = {"val1": ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'sum'],
    72   1602.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1                           "val2": ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'sum']}
    73   1585.3 MiB    -17.6 MiB           1       return df_filtered.groupby('range_id').agg(aggregation_dict).reset_index()


# Nayem_aggregate_range
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    19    905.9 MiB    905.9 MiB           1   def Nayem_aggregate_range(df, ranges):
    20    905.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       results = []
    21    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          21       for idx, row in ranges.iterrows():
    22    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20           mask = (
    23    961.5 MiB     55.6 MiB          60               (df['group'] == row['group']) &
    24    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20               (df['start'] >= row['start']) &
    25    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20               (df['end'] <= row['end'])
    26                                                 )
    27    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20           filtered_df = df[mask]
    28    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20           if not filtered_df.empty:
    29    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20               agg_dict = {
    30    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20                   'val1_min': filtered_df['val1'].min(),
    31    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20                   'val1_max': filtered_df['val1'].max(),
    32    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20                   'val1_mean': filtered_df['val1'].mean(),
    33    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20                   'val1_sum': filtered_df['val1'].sum(),
    34    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20                   'val2_min': filtered_df['val2'].min(),
    35    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20                   'val2_max': filtered_df['val2'].max(),
    36    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20                   'val2_mean': filtered_df['val2'].mean(),
    37    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20                   'val2_sum': filtered_df['val2'].sum(),
    38                                                     }
    39    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20               agg_dict['range_id'] = idx
    40    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB          20               results.append(agg_dict)
    41    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       aggregated_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    42    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       aggregated_df = aggregated_df.set_index('range_id')
    43    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       aggregated_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    44    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           [('val1', 'min'), ('val1', 'max'), ('val1', 'mean'), ('val1', 'sum'),
    45                                                  ('val2', 'min'), ('val2', 'max'), ('val2', 'mean'), ('val2', 'sum')]
    46                                             )
    47    961.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return aggregated_df


# user24714692_merge_agg_
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     3    879.9 MiB    879.9 MiB           1   def user24714692_merge_agg_(df, ranges):
     4   1429.1 MiB    549.2 MiB           1       mdf = pd.merge(df, ranges, on='group', suffixes=('', '_range'))
     5                                         
     6   1527.7 MiB     70.3 MiB           2       fdf = mdf[
     7   1457.4 MiB     19.1 MiB           2           (mdf['start'] >= mdf['start_range']) &
     8   1438.3 MiB      9.2 MiB           1           (mdf['end'] <= mdf['end_range'])
     9                                             ]
    10                                         
    11   1527.9 MiB      0.3 MiB           3       res = fdf.groupby(['group', 'start_range', 'end_range']).agg({
    12   1527.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           'val1': ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'sum'],
    13   1527.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           'val2': ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'sum']
    14   1527.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       }).reset_index()
    15                                         
    16   1527.9 MiB      0.0 MiB          14       res.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() if col[1] else col[0] for col in res.columns.values]
    17   1527.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return res

Maximum memory usage


you could get more performance by computing the aggregation individually before concatenating - but i guess OP can handle that

Not sure I follow you @sammywemmy, do you mean a pd.concat in a loop on the groups?

so create the grouped object, create each aggregation, then combine the list of aggregated values via pd.concat. odd route but  coud be faster (based on personal experience ... YMMV)

@sammywemmy IIUC, then you'd need an unstack step to have the same format. This seems less efficient

Added a code snippet of what I had in mind - in this instance there is no perf difference

@sammywemmy I see (you forgot the grouped = out.groupby('group')), It's indeed faster

deleted. hope it made sense

@sammywemmy You can leave it (format it nicely) and I'll update the timings. Or add your own answer.

i'll leave it to you. I dont think there is a need for another answer as yours does the job very well. just sharing knowledge, and learning as well

@sammywemmy updated, thanks for your feedback :)

@mozway excellent answer thank you, I should've been explicit that in some cases the same group may have multiple ranges as ouroboros pointed out. I edited my question to reflect that. On a different note, I was also wondering if polars might be better suited for something like this...

To achieve efficiently, you have to utilize Pandas powerful groupby and aggregation capabilities :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_df = {
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
    'start': [10, 20, 15, 30, 25],
    'end': [50, 40, 60, 70, 45],
    'val1': ['5', '10', '11', '12', '6'],
    'val2': ['5', '2', '1', '1', '0'],
}

data_ranges = {
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'start': [0, 5, 25],
    'end': [50, 7, 35],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
ranges = pd.DataFrame(data_ranges)

df['val1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['val1'])
df['val2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['val2'])

def aggregate_range(df, ranges):
    results = []
    for idx, row in ranges.iterrows():
        mask = (
            (df['group'] == row['group']) &
            (df['start'] >= row['start']) &
            (df['end'] <= row['end'])
        )
        filtered_df = df[mask]
        if not filtered_df.empty:
            agg_dict = {
                'val1_min': filtered_df['val1'].min(),
                'val1_max': filtered_df['val1'].max(),
                'val1_mean': filtered_df['val1'].mean(),
                'val1_sum': filtered_df['val1'].sum(),
                'val2_min': filtered_df['val2'].min(),
                'val2_max': filtered_df['val2'].max(),
                'val2_mean': filtered_df['val2'].mean(),
                'val2_sum': filtered_df['val2'].sum(),
            }
            agg_dict['range_id'] = idx
            results.append(agg_dict)
    return pd.DataFrame(results)

aggregated_df = aggregate_range(df, ranges)

aggregated_df = aggregated_df.set_index('range_id')
aggregated_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [('val1', 'min'), ('val1', 'max'), ('val1', 'mean'), ('val1', 'sum'),
     ('val2', 'min'), ('val2', 'max'), ('val2', 'mean'), ('val2', 'sum')]
)

print(aggregated_df)



Iterrows is certainly not fast

@sammywemmy it's actually not that dramatic for large DataFrames and it's memory efficient. I added some timings/memory profiling to my answer.

nice! good job @mozway

thinking about it now, iterrows will be memory efficient because it is doing one row at a time, that makes sense. peformance however i expect to be poor (everything is relative I guess) as the data size (of ranges grow), the larger ranges  become the slower generally it becomes

That's probably true, I used up to 20 groups in my tests, that might become worse for more groups (although groupby will also be affected)

Here is a memory inefficient solution:
ranges['range_id'] = ranges.index
df_merged = pd.merge(df, ranges, on='group')
df_filtered = df_merged[(df_merged['start_x'] >= df_merged['start_y'])
                        & (df_merged['end_x'] <= df_merged['end_y'])]
aggregation_dict = {"val1": ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'sum'],
                    "val2": ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'sum']}
result = df_filtered.groupby('range_id').agg(aggregation_dict).reset_index()


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'start': [10, 20, 30, 15, 25, 35],
    'end': [50, 60, 70, 55, 65, 75],
    'val1': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
    'val2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
})
print(df)
'''
  group  start  end  val1  val2
0     A     10   50     5     5
1     A     20   60    10     6
2     A     30   70    15     7
3     B     15   55    20     8
4     B     25   65    25     9
5     B     35   75    30    10
'''
ranges = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A', 'B'],
    'start': [5, 10],
    'end': [40, 60]
})

# Convert ranges to a dictionary for quick lookup
range_dict = {group: (start, end) for group, start, end in ranges.values}
print(range_dict)#{'A': (5, 40), 'B': (10, 60)}

m1 = df['start'] >= df['group'].map(range_dict).str[0].values

m2 = df['end'] <= df['group'].map(range_dict).str[1].values

filtered_indices = np.where(m1 & m2)[0]
print(filtered_indices)#[3]

filtered_df = df.iloc[filtered_indices]
'''
 group  start  end  val1  val2
3     B     15   55    20     8
'''
# Aggregate using groupby and strings for functions
cols= ['val1', 'val2']
agg_functions = ['min','max','mean','sum']

res = filtered_df.groupby('group')[cols].agg({'val1':agg_functions,'val2':agg_functions}).reset_index()
print(res)
'''
 group val1               val2             
         min max  mean sum  min max mean sum
0     B   20  20  20.0  20    8   8  8.0   8
'''

